# stunnel without stunnel client or without admin rights

Tags: linux, windows, https, tunnel, stunnel

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I would like to access my SSL tunnel that is set on a Linux box without a stunnel client from the Windows box.

This is because I don't have admin rights on the Windows box.

Is this possible ? If yes how.

If not, how can I still tunnel my traffic with stunnel without admin rights?

Answer (score 1):

At the network stack level you route the VPN traffic over the Linux box. However, you would have to change the routing table on the Windows box, which also requires admin privileges.

An alternative is using a SOCKS proxy on the Linux host. If your client applications supports this, you can use the the SOCKS proxy to forward traffic.